# General Measure Spaces and its construction

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Show that any measure that is induced by an outer measure is complete.

I approached this problem by taking a subset $A$ of another set, call it $B$. For any set $E$, take the measure of it to get zero. Since the intersection of $A$ and $E$ is a subset of $B$ and the measure of the complement of $A$ intersection $E$ is equal to the measure of $E$.

My problem is how to figure out if the induce part is complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $m^*$ be the outer measure. If $E$ is measurable and $m(E)=0$ then $m^*(E)=0$.

If $F\subset E$ then $$0\leq m^*(F)\leq m^*(E)=0$$

Therefore we just need to prove that if $m^*(F)=0$ then $F$ is measurable (and therefore $m(F)=m^*(F)=0$), i.e. we need to prove that for all $G$ 
$$m^*(F)=m^*(F\cap G)+m^*(F\setminus G)$$

But $F\cap G\subset F$ and $F\setminus G\subset F$. Therefore $m^*(F\cap G)=m^*(F\setminus G)=0$.

Comment: Thanks @Pp.. That certainly helps. I was probably thinking too hard then.